# Inject property in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I need to inject a property in the web.xml, for exemple I want to parameter the timeout for the session with something like that :

web.xml :

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>${timeout}</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

timeout.config :

```
  timeout=[TIMEOUT]
```

How can I do it ?
Thanks